# Effect of nosuid on executables inside the mounted filesystem

Tags: linux, mount, setuid

Let it be known that I barely understand what setuid/setgid/whatever is. I *think* it has something to do with what user a program is executed as. This brings me to `nosuid`.

In [Security Enhancements in Android 4.3](https://source.android.com/security/enhancements/enhancements43.html), Google says

```
The /system partition is now mounted nosuid for zygote-spawned processes,
preventing Android applications from executing setuid programs.
```

It makes no sense to me to say that a filesystem in Linux is mounted "for" anything, as if the way it is mounted can be relative to a process or executable. If the system partition on Android devices is mounted with `nosuid`, then how can any of the system's core executables run as root, which they need to do in the earliest stages of startup?

Answer (score 8):

Possibly relevant line earlier in the same document:

> **No setuid/setgid programs.** Added support for filesystem capabilities to Android system files and removed all setuid/setguid programs.  This reduces root attack surface and the likelihood of potential security vulnerabilities.

Regarding your final question:

> If the system partition on Android devices is mounted with nosuid, then how can any of the system's core executables run as root, which they need to do in the earliest stages of startup?

`nosuid` doesn't prevent **`root`** from running processes.  It is *not* the same as `noexec`.  It just prevents the `suid` bit on executables from taking effect, which by definition means that a user cannot then run an application that would have permission to do things that the user doesn't have permission to do himself.

Also relevant here is an understanding of what "zygote" actually is; try reading https://android.stackexchange.com/a/77308

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not an Android expert.</sub>

Comment: So it's like disabling `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, similar.  `sudo` itself has its `suid` bit set, as you can see by running `ls -l $(which sudo)`.  Another common `suid` utility is `passwd`; it has to run with `root` permissions so it can edit `/etc/passwd`.  Note that `suid` doesn't actually mean "run with `root` permissions"; it means "run with the permissions of the executable's owner rather than the permissions of the user who runs the executable."  However, the most common `suid` executables you see are owned by `root`.

Comment: To play with `suid` settings on your own box, you can run `cp /bin/ls /tmp/ ; sudo chown someuser /tmp/ls ; sudo chmod 4755 /tmp/ls ; /tmp/ls ~someuser`  You'll be able to list the contents of `someuser`'s home directory, because the modified copy of the `ls` binary runs with `someuser`'s permissions rather than yours (with no `sudo` required).  And, if you try `/tmp/ls ~` you will get "permission denied" because `someuser` *doesn't* have permissions to list *your* home directory.